# How to define signature of a callable argument?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a function that accepts a callable

```py
def foo(bar):
    print(bar(1, 2))
```

What is the best way to declare that `bar(..)` accepts two ints and returns a str?
Is there a more well-defined way than just documentation?

Comment: See [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) and the documentation for the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing) module.

Comment: Use type hinting from the ```typing``` module. Go to the section about [callables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Callable` type from `typing` lets you specify both the argument types and the return type of a callable value.

```
from typing import Callable

def foo(bar: Callable[[int,int],str]):
    print(bar(1, 2))
```

Note that since Python is dynamically typed, a type hint is, to some extent, just documentation. Third-party tools like `mypy`, though, can be used for *static* type analysis to help ensure that your code doesn't pass a value of the wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

Python is dynamically typed which means the interpreter type checks as the code runs, and the type can change over time.

[PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) introduced type hints. You can do this by the following syntax:

```
def bar( a: int, b: int) -> str:
    return 

def foo(bar: callable) -> None:
    print(bar(1, 2))
```

Comment: bar is provided by the user of foo, I can't define it.